# Issues installing SRILM (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: command-line, compiling

I have been trying to install SRILM to use with Kaldi and have run into a particularly frustrating issue.

To create a clear timeline of actions, here goes:

I downloaded the tar.gz from the SRILM website.

I extracted the file into a subdirectory in my home folder (`/Home/Speech/SRILM`) using the file manager program included with Ubuntu.

I changed the `SRILM =` line in the makefile to `SRILM = /Home/Speech/SRILM`.

I did not change anything else in the makefile because I am running Linux x86_64 and the instructions state that this should be able to compile out of the box (which I am beginning to doubt).

I attempted to make and was met with the following error.

```
make: /Home/Speech/SRILM/sbin/machine-type: Command not found
Makefile:13: /Home/Speech/SRILM/common/Makefile.common.variables: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/Home/Speech/SRILM/common/Makefile.common.variables'. Stop.
```

All of the paths, files, and directories exist, so I am confused as to why the program is incapable of finding them.

If there is a well made, step by step guide to installing/compiling SRILM I would greatly appreciate a link. I have attempted to find one and all the ones I have found (including the instructions in the install file) appear to be missing some steps/not very clear.

Solution: Replaced Home with `/home/username`, learned a bit more about Ubuntu filesystems.

Comment: `Home` isn't a real directory: it's just what the file manager (nautilus) uses as a shorthand for the user's home directory, otherwise known in the shell as `$HOME`. It usually expands to `/home/username` (where `username` is replaced by your actual login name) but you should confirm by running `echo $HOME` in a terminal.

Comment: Just edited the makefile and changed Home to /home/myusername and ran make again, process ran. There may be other errors, but this one is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Home` isn't a real directory: it's just what the file manager (nautilus) uses as a shorthand for the user's home directory, otherwise known in the shell as `$HOME`.

It usually expands to `/home/username` (where username is replaced by your actual login name) but you should confirm by running `echo $HOME` in a terminal.